# Detecting CTRL inside CEdit::OnChar and testing nChar value?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cedit

I derived my own control from `CEdit` and it behaves as I intend:

```
#define IsSHIFTpressed() ( (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & (1 << (sizeof(SHORT)*8-1))) != 0   )

void CEditEx::OnChar(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
    if (IsCTRLpressed() && nChar == 2)
    {
        // Do something
        return;
    }

    if (IsCTRLpressed() && nChar == 9)
    {
        // Do something
        return;
    }

    CEdit::OnChar(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
}
```

However, I have two questions about how I am detecting the key press:

1. Is it possible to detect <kbd>CTRL</kbd> being pressed from inside `OnChar` without the need to use `GetKeyState`?
2. Are there any constants for comparing against `"b"` (2) and `"i"` (9)? I only knew I needed to use those numeric values from when I debugged into the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noted, the value of the `nChar` argument to `OnChar` for keyboard entries of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + "a letter" (independent of the case) will be the ASCII "control-key" values, 1 (for "a") thru 26 (for "z").

To answer your *second* point: a search through the `<WinUser.h>` header file shows no `VK_xxx` tokens for these; however, be aware that some of these control codes are used (by convention) for other actions: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (decimal 13) is equivalent to <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the header has `#define VK_RETURN 0x0D`; further, for one of your *specific* cases, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (9) is the ASCII `TAB` character, and the header, accordingly, has the `#define VK_TAB 0x09` definition.

Although the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> ASCII code (0x02) is much less used these days (`STX`, or "Start of Text"), that value is used by Windows for the right mouse button (`#define VK_RBUTTON 0x02`).

So, to answer your *first* point: Yes, you will need to make the `GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL)` check! Without that, a right-click will likely give you a false <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key will give a false <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Furthermore, though I have no 'hard evidence' other than your own investigations, I think that a right-click *while the Control key is down* will generate a different value for `nChar` (i.e. *not* 2), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will generate an `nChar` different from that for <kbd>Tab</kbd> alone.